# How can we generalize the constructor with the variable formatting in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, constructor, cypress

Suppose,

**My Code:**

```js
var slist = ['ec', 'ce', 'ke']

for(let s in slist){
   const s1 = slist[s]

   //here, AWS is class Name and it has methods which are in slist.

   const ec2 = new AWS.s1()
}
```

**Requirement:** Now, when creating the constructor with the methods of AWS class, I want that s1 variable which is having method name should create a constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `AWS.ec`, `AWS.ke`, `AWS.ce` are the properties used when hard-coded, you can access then via a variable using square-bracket notation

```js
const slist = ['ec', 'ce', 'ke']

slist.forEach(s => {
  const ec2 = new AWS[s]()
```